# Newspaper3k Library - scraping behind paywalls

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, python-newspaper

Is there a way to use the Newspaper3k library to scrape behind paywalls if you have a subscription?

As we don't have direct access to the URL request method, I'm not sure how we can, for example, pass in a session cookie. Is there any way, maybe better, to do this?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to log in to the subscription service using selenium and query the site with newspaper.  If you still need help please let me know the target site and I will put together some code.